# FindMy Friends incorrect street and town address

Tags: geolocation, find-my-friends

In FindMy app my parents have shared their location. When they are home, the location view shows their correct geolocation, but the street address and town are incorrect. If I copy the address as shown in “FindMy” into maps or google maps it locates the address in a completely different place; In the town that the address is (the next town to where they live), not the location of my parents house. They live in a rural part of New Hampshire.

How can I report an incorrect street address in this app?

Answer (score 1):

You can report any bugs with native Apple applications here: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome